# Escape for comments in SQL files with liquibase

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hsqldb, liquibase

I am working with liquibase and a hsqldb database.
I have a .sql file with 'insert' instructions for filling the database at the bootstrap, but if a string contains two minus signs close to each other it is interpreted as a comment and not as string.
Here my sql instruction in the .sql file loaded by liquibase:

```
INSERT INTO user (id,firstname,lastname,mystring) VALUES
(11,'Wendy','Salinas','this is my string--and it continues'),
(12,'Kirsten','Parker','this is the string of Kirsten')
```

And my stacktrace:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO user     (id,firstname,lastname,mystring) VALUES
(11,'Wendy','Salinas','this is my string
(12,'Kirsten','Parker','this is the string of Kristen')
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: KIRSTEN required: ) : line: 12
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
```

Is there a way to escape comments in strings for sql file consumed by liquibase? 
How can I escape '--' in a string in a .sql file consumed by liquibase?

Comment: You should report this in the Liquibase forum. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes, I did. http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000000708003 but for the moment no answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSQLDB allows you to work around this limitation by breaking the string in two parts:

```
INSERT INTO user (id,firstname,lastname,mystring) VALUES
(11,'Wendy','Salinas','this is my string-'  '-and it continues'),
(12,'Kirsten','Parker','this is the string of Kirsten')
```

In the next version 2.3.0 you can also use unicode strings with user-defined escapes.